# Why does Post request for an endpoint with same payload returns http 400 for url without trailing slash?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In my controller class , I have an annotated post request method like shown below

```
@RestController(value="/api")
public class ApiController{

 @PostMapping("/post")
 @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
 public ResponseObject postMethod(RequestObject obj){
  //service calls
```

when I call my endpoint with

> POST `http://localhost:8989/api/post/`

with payload my request succesfully hits my controller method.

On the contrary if I only change my request to url with no trailing slash

> POST `http://localhost:8989/api/post`

with exact same payload I get following response from server

```
{
"timestamp": "2022-11-29T11:23:36.153+03:00",
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"message": "",
"path": "/api/post"
}
```

I enable web logs for spring and below is my trace when I get http 400 from server

> [2022-11-29 11:23:36,153] [CID:] [RID:] [http-nio-8989-exec-1] TRACE      --- DispatcherServlet : "ERROR" dispatch for POST "/error", parameters={}, headers={masked} in DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'[2022-11-29 11:23:36,153] [CID:] [RID:] [http-nio-8989-exec-1] TRACE ---
> RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
> [2022-11-29 11:23:36,153] [CID:] [RID:] [http-nio-8989-exec-1] TRACE --- HandlerMethod : Arguments: [SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@3660b306]]]
> [2022-11-29 11:23:36,153] [CID:] [RID:] [http-nio-8989-exec-1] DEBUG --- HttpEntityMethodProcessor : Using 'application/json', given [application/json] and supported [application/xml;charset=UTF-8, text/xml;charset=UTF-8, application/*+xml;charset=UTF-8, application/json, application/*+json, application/x-jackson-smile]
> [2022-11-29 11:23:36,154] [CID:] [RID:] [http-nio-8989-exec-1] TRACE --- HttpEntityMethodProcessor : Writing [{timestamp=Tue Nov 29 11:23:36 TRT 2022, status=400, error=Bad Request, message=, path=/api/loanaccount/cancelLimitTransaction}]
> [2022-11-29 11:23:36,154] [CID:] [RID:] [http-nio-8989-exec-1] TRACE --- DispatcherServlet : No view rendering, null ModelAndView returned.

I was thinking that if it was a client error , I should have not be able to succesfully call it by just appending trailing slash to url.Because my payload didn't change. How should I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Where is @PostRequest from?

Comment: Sorry. There was a typo. Edited question.